# Django Action Append Slash

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, drf-yasg

I am making development, and my POST request come like **config/alert** and I am trying to catch it with action decorater below.BUT Django does not catch it It wants **config/alert/** but It is not possible to change incoming url add the SLASH.

```
@action(methods=['post'], detail=False, url_path='alert')
def get_post(self, request, pk=None, *args, **kwargs):
```

How can I modify the action to listen without slash in **POST** request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution adding extra APIView and putting ? end of the re_path in urls.py

```
re_path(r'alerta_forward/alert/?', post_data)
```

With using ? it became option slash, then I called an APIView.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have to check the `APPEND_SLASH` setting in your settings.py file.
You can find more information about option here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#append-slash